# How to rewrite this radicand as a perfect square.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm not sure how to rewrite $$\sqrt{162+81e^{18t}+81e^{-18t}}$$ in the form $\sqrt{\text{something}^2}$. It says to keep in mind that $e^{z} \cdot e^{-z}=1$. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

$$81e^{18t}+81e^{-18t}+162=(9e^{9t})^2+(9e^{-9t})^2+2(9e^{9t})(9e^{-9t})$$

Do you recognize $$a^2+b^2+2ab?$$

Comment: @DanielClemente., My Pleasure. Also have a look into https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws